# Setting hyperparameters of the LDA model in vowpal wabbit

Tags: apache-spark, lda, vowpalwabbit

I am a typical, regular, everyday Spark user. In [Spark's LDA](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda) there are hyperparameters thats stands for

> `docConcentration`: Hyperparameter for prior over documents’ distributions over topics. Currently must be > 1, where larger values encourage smoother inferred distributions.
>   `topicConcentration`: Hyperparameter for prior over topics’ distributions over terms (words). Currently must be > 1, where larger values encourage smoother inferred distributions.

which corresponds to typically assigned in the literature $\alpha$ and $\beta$ parameters for which (and $k$ - number of topics) the log-likelihood function of the LDA model is optimized during the convergence process.

Does anyone know if there is any option to set such arguments/parameters prior in [vowpal wabbit's LDA](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Latent-Dirichlet-Allocation) model?

Comment: I updated the [wiki](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Latent-Dirichlet-Allocation) with documentation of the Dirichlet priors and all other LDA hyperparameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this description of vw lda.](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/lda.pdf)!
I think the parameters mentioned on 13th slide might be the ones that you are looking for.

Comment: That's what I was exactly looking for. Thanks @langusta

Comment: `vw -h --lda 1 | grep -A 3 lda`

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, the LDA implementation offers the following hyperparameters:

```
Latent Dirichlet Allocation:
  --lda arg                             Run lda with <int> topics

  --lda_alpha arg (=0.100000001)        Prior on sparsity of per-document topic
                                        weights
  --lda_rho arg (=0.100000001)          Prior on sparsity of topic 
                                        distributions
  --lda_D arg (=10000)                  Number of documents
  --lda_epsilon arg (=0.00100000005)    Loop convergence threshold
  --minibatch arg (=1)                  Minibatch size, for LDA
  --math-mode arg (=0)                  Math mode: simd, accuracy, fast-approx
  --metrics arg (=0)                    Compute metrics
```

You can find the source code for implementation details [here](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/4eeecd343392923928fb0e256df01bd601062edb/vowpalwabbit/lda_core.cc#L1280-L1293).

Or directly jump into the [source code of vw utility](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/4eeecd343392923928fb0e256df01bd601062edb/utl/vw-lda#L350-L391) which offers slightly different parameters.